Windows Server 2016 Deduplication garbage collection error
I have Windows Server 2016 with a 3,5 TB volume that has Windows Deduplication enabled.
Savings are 50% according the console.
Issue: Garbage collection run gives an error:

The Data Deduplication service detected an internal folder that is not secure. To secure the folder, reinstall deduplication on the volume.

Is it possible to solve this issue without uninstalling the Deduplication feature?
There are additional volumes on the server that also have the Deduplication enabled without having the issue.
These would also then be affected and I do not have enough free storage available to accommodate.
Any tips are welcomed to solve this issue.
